# Unable to perform rake tasks in production environment due to psql permissions

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, rake, digital-ocean

I have set up a rake task that I want to run once an hour using a cron expression. I got it working locally on my dev environment, but I can't get it to work on my production environment (hosted on digitalocean) because I'm running into postgres permission issues.

This is the code I have in /lib/tasks/cron.rake:

```
  task :cron => :environment do
    puts "starting job"
    Schedule.run_schedules
    puts "finished job"
  end
```

When I run rake cron in development, it results in this output:

```
starting job
finished job
```

When I ssh into my production environment and run the following command:

```
rake cron RAILS_ENV=production
```

I get the following output:

```
starting job
rake aborted!
ActiveRecord::NoDatabaseError: FATAL:  role "root" does not exist
```

I figured I need to run this as the user that owns psql, so I ran the following commands:

```
su user
rake cron RAILS_ENV=production
```

But then I get this message:

```
rake aborted!
LoadError: cannot load such file -- bundler/setup
```

Running

```
bundler
```

results in:

```
Command 'bundler' not found, but can be installed with:

apt install ruby-bundler
Please ask your administrator.
```

I tried installing bundler by sudo apt install ruby-bundler, but then it tells me I don't have the correct permissions.

I'm completely lost here. Any help is much appreciated!

EDIT:
I also tried

```
psql -U user
psql -U user -w
```

both result in

```
psql: FATAL:  Peer authentication failed for user "user"
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this problem is related to the user authentication on `database.yml`
Because whenever you change into production, you are applying a different database, and therefor a different user and password.

Try the same command after changing your database.yml config, use the same database in the production as you use in development just for testing, and then you can refactor to run accordingly in the server.